# Create attribute element with the same name as existing attribute in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML input with elements that have a number of attributes. I don't know in advance, which attributes.

I'd like to create an attribute element of the same name for each of the existing attributes.

Input:

```
<elem id="1" name="test" version="2" />
<elem id="2" check="true" base="dir"/>
```

output:

```
<newelem newattribute="bla" newattribute2="blabla" id="1" name="test" version="2"/>
<newelem newattribute="bla" newattribute2="blabla" id="2" check="true" base="dir"/>
```

I tried this:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="name(.)" select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

But the name() function doesn't work here, it seems.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simpler way, just use `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>`

Comment: aaah, right, I always forget about those copy-elements. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

put name function between {}

```
 <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}" select="."/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can surround the call to `name(.)` with curly braces:

```
<xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}" select="."/>
```